# wxPython | wxDataViewListCtrl get all selected rows/items

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxformbuilder

I`m using wxPython in conjunctions with wxFormBuilder.
I have a wxDataViewListCtrl with 5 columns to list my values.
The user can select one or more rows (style = wxDV_MULTIPLE).
If the user only select one row i can catch it with this method:

```
def showContextTZM( self, event ):
    if self.m_dvlc.HasSelection():
        item_id = event.GetItem().GetID()
```

If the user selects more than one row I only get the item where the cursor is placed.
I did not find any method to get all selected items.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the functionality you need is not documented (at least in the only really usable wxPython/Phoenix docs). It is indeed present in the [current wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_data_view_ctrl.html#a94098d3611634d880e7035b254c41c86). But you can find it in the wxPython package:

wxPython classic, in `wx.dataview`:

```
def GetSelections(*args, **kwargs):
    """GetSelections(self) -> DataViewItemArray"""
    return _dataview.DataViewCtrl_GetSelections(*args, **kwargs)
```

wxPython Phoenix, in `.../site-packages/wx/dataview.pi`

```
def GetSelections(self):
    """
    GetSelections() -> DataViewItemArray

    Returns a list of the currently selected items.
    """
```

It works at least in classic 2.9/3.0 (not tested by me for Phoenix).